# Link to external url in angular redirects to application

Tags: html, angular, routes

Might be a simple question but I'm new to Angular.

I've set my routing setup already in the navbar, but I have a link that links to an external url, and when I click on it, it redirects me back to the application, not even in the home path ( HomeComponent is missing )

The link looks like this :

```
 <a href="www.stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">
```

Here's my routing paths :

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'a-propos', component: AProposComponent },
    { path: 'savoir', component: SavoirComponent },
    { path: 'diplomes', component: DiplomesComponent },
    { path: 'expérience', component: ExperienceComponent },
    { path: 'portfolio', component: PortfolioComponent },
    { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent },
];
```

Comment: This is on a mobile device and the protocol handler is opening the application (if installed) instead of going to the website?

Comment: @Mathias Nope I'm currently using a desktop. On hovering the link, it gives me this : "localhost:4200/www.stackoverflow.com" I bet it has something to do with the base tag in the head ?

Comment: Try it with http:// or https:// before the URL

Comment: You rock, that was it ! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with http:// or https:// before the URL